# iOS - Play streaming(mp3) audio with effects

Tags: iphone, core-audio, audio-streaming

I am new to iOS Audio Technology.

I am developing an application which will play streaming audio(mp3), planning to add some effects like iPod Equalizer , Pan Control.

What is best way to achieve this.

> _*I have tried to use Matt Gallagher's **AudioStreamer** API ( http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html ). I was able to play the streaming audio. but i was not sure how to add the effects using **AudioQueue** _*.

From Apple Documentation, i understood that **AudioUnit** can be used to add Effects. But streaming format should be in Linear PCM.

Basically i want to add Effects and play streaming audio.

I am confused now to way forward.

Could some one give a direction to way forward. any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Sasikumar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use AudioUnits definitively.

Look how simple it is:

**1) Create AudioUnits**

```
// OUTPUT unit
AudioComponentDescription iOUnitDescription;
iOUnitDescription.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
iOUnitDescription.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
iOUnitDescription.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
iOUnitDescription.componentFlags = 0;
iOUnitDescription.componentFlagsMask = 0;

// MIXER unit
AudioComponentDescription MixerUnitDescription;
MixerUnitDescription.componentType          = kAudioUnitType_Mixer;
MixerUnitDescription.componentSubType       = kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer;
MixerUnitDescription.componentManufacturer  = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
MixerUnitDescription.componentFlags         = 0;
MixerUnitDescription.componentFlagsMask     = 0;

// PLAYER unit
AudioComponentDescription playerUnitDescription;
playerUnitDescription.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Generator;
playerUnitDescription.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer;
playerUnitDescription.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

// EQ unit
AudioComponentDescription EQUnitDescription;
EQUnitDescription.componentType          = kAudioUnitType_Effect;
EQUnitDescription.componentSubType       = kAudioUnitSubType_AUiPodEQ;
EQUnitDescription.componentManufacturer  = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
EQUnitDescription.componentFlags         = 0;
EQUnitDescription.componentFlagsMask     = 0;
```

etc.

**2) Create Nodes**

```
////
//// EQ NODE
////
err = AUGraphAddNode(processingGraph, &EQUnitDescription, &eqNode);
if (err) { NSLog(@"eqNode err = %ld", err); }

////
//// FX NODE
////
err = AUGraphAddNode(processingGraph, &FXUnitDescription, &fxNode);
if (err) { NSLog(@"fxNode err = %ld", err); }

////
//// VFX NODE
////
err = AUGraphAddNode(processingGraph, &VFXUnitDescription, &vfxNode);
if (err) { NSLog(@"vfxNode err = %ld", err); }

///
/// MIXER NODE
///
err = AUGraphAddNode (processingGraph, &MixerUnitDescription, &mixerNode );
if (err) { NSLog(@"mixerNode err = %ld", err); }

///
/// OUTPUT NODE
///
err = AUGraphAddNode(processingGraph, &iOUnitDescription, &ioNode);
if (err) { NSLog(@"outputNode err = %ld", err); }

////
/// PLAYER NODE
///
err = AUGraphAddNode(processingGraph, &playerUnitDescription, &audioPlayerNode);
if (err) { NSLog(@"audioPlayerNode err = %ld", err); }
```

**3) Connect them**

```
//// mic /lineIn ----> vfx bus 0
err =   AUGraphConnectNodeInput(processingGraph, ioNode, 1, vfxNode, 0);
if (err) { NSLog(@"vfxNode err = %ld", err); }

//// vfx ----> mixer
err =   AUGraphConnectNodeInput(processingGraph, vfxNode, 0, mixerNode, micBus );
if (err) { NSLog(@"vfxNode err = %ld", err); }

//// player ----> fx
err = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(processingGraph, audioPlayerNode, 0, fxNode, 0);
if (err) { NSLog(@"audioPlayerNode err = %ld", err); }

//// fx ----> mixer
err = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(processingGraph, fxNode, 0, mixerNode, filePlayerBus);
if (err) { NSLog(@"audioPlayerNode err = %ld", err); }

///// mixer ----> eq
err = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(processingGraph, mixerNode, 0, eqNode, 0);
if (err) { NSLog(@"mixerNode err = %ld", err); }

//// eq ----> output
err = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(processingGraph, eqNode, 0, ioNode, 0);
if (err) { NSLog(@"eqNode err = %ld", err); }
```

**4) Setup render callbacks**

```
    // let's say a mic input callback
    AURenderCallbackStruct lineInrCallbackStruct = {};
    lineInrCallbackStruct.inputProc = &micLineInCallback;
    lineInrCallbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (void*)self;
    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(
                           vfxUnit,
                           kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                           kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                           0,
                           &lineInrCallbackStruct,
                           sizeof(lineInrCallbackStruct));
```

**5) Processing audio buffers in the callback**

```
static OSStatus micLineInCallback (void                 *inRefCon,
                                   AudioUnitRenderActionFlags   *ioActionFlags,
                                   const AudioTimeStamp         *inTimeStamp,
                                   UInt32                       inBusNumber,
                                   UInt32                       inNumberFrames,
                                   AudioBufferList              *ioData)
{
    MixerHostAudio *THIS = (MixerHostAudio *)inRefCon;
    AudioUnit rioUnit = THIS.ioUnit;    // io unit which has the input data from mic/lineIn
    OSStatus renderErr;
    OSStatus err;
    UInt32 bus1 = 1;                    // input bus
    int i;

    renderErr = AudioUnitRender(
                                   rioUnit,
                                   ioActionFlags,
                                   inTimeStamp,
                                   bus1,
                                   inNumberFrames,
                                   ioData);

     //// do something with iOData like getting left and right channels

AudioUnitSampleType *inSamplesLeft;         // convenience pointers to sample data
    AudioUnitSampleType *inSamplesRight;

    int isStereo;               // c boolean - for deciding how many channels to process.
    int numberOfChannels;       // 1 = mono, 2= stereo

    // Sint16 buffers to hold sample data after conversion

    SInt16 *sampleBufferLeft = THIS.conversionBufferLeft;
    SInt16 *sampleBufferRight = THIS.conversionBufferRight;
    SInt16 *sampleBuffer;

    // start the actual processing

    numberOfChannels = THIS.displayNumberOfInputChannels;
    isStereo = numberOfChannels > 1 ? 1 : 0;  // decide stereo or mono


    // copy all the input samples to the callback buffer - after this point we could bail and have a pass through

    renderErr = AudioUnitRender(rioUnit, ioActionFlags,
                                inTimeStamp, bus1, inNumberFrames, ioData);
    if (renderErr < 0) {
        return renderErr;
    }

    inSamplesLeft = (AudioUnitSampleType *) ioData->mBuffers[0].mData; // left channel
    fixedPointToSInt16(inSamplesLeft, sampleBufferLeft, inNumberFrames);

    if(isStereo) {
        inSamplesRight = (AudioUnitSampleType *) ioData->mBuffers[1].mData; // right channel
        fixedPointToSInt16(inSamplesRight, sampleBufferRight, inNumberFrames);
    }
```

I've learned this by exploring Apple great docs like

[Apple MixerHost](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/ConstructingAudioUnitApps/ConstructingAudioUnitApps.html) audio unit application

[The Audio Unit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) by Apple

[AudioGraph](http://zerokidz.com/audiograph/Home.html) is the most comprehensive example code / "unofficial" documentation you can have on real world AudioUnit programming.

Hope this help, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

have a look at PureData audio process - libpd is ios version of it